# How do I select the latest/newest (based on timestamp) N elements with XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have following sample xml:

```
  <datas>
     <data>
        <id>1</id>
        <timestamp>2013-01-19T14:20:01.000+02:00</timestamp>
     </data>
     <data>
        <id>2</id>
        <timestamp>2013-09-13T14:52:34.000+02:00</timestamp>
     </data>
     <data>
        <id>3</id>
        <timestamp>2013-10-02T12:47:47.000+02:00</timestamp>
     </data>
     <data>
        <id>4</id>
        <timestamp>2013-10-23T14:52:08.000+02:00</timestamp>
     </data>
     <data>
        <id>5</id>
        <timestamp>2013-07-23T14:55:20.000+02:00</timestamp>
     </data>
     <data>
        <id>6</id>
        <timestamp>2013-10-02T12:44:24.000+02:00</timestamp>
     </data>
  </datas>
```

I can get last 3 elements with following xpath:
//data[position()>last()-3]/*:id,','
This will return id: 4,5,6

What I need is to get 3 elements with latest (max) timestamp. I could use max function to get latest element (but i want n=3 latest elements) - t.i elements with id: 3,4,6.

Is this possible using only xpath? I use XPath 2.0.

Comment: It's certainly possible using XPath 2.0. Which version are you using?

Comment: @MichaelKay: Is this really true? So far I've found only negative answers regarding sorting in _pure_ XPath. What seems to be available. though, are helper classes in a variety of programming languages and frameworks that add a sorting functionality. If you don't have access to these, but have to rely on one single XPath expression I guess you're out of luck.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't read the question carefully enough first time round, a week later I'm not sure what I was thinking. It

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure XPath solution, it's a bit dirty but it does the job:

```
<ul>
<xsl:for-each select="datas/data">
    <xsl:sort select="translate(translate(translate(translate(translate(timestamp,'-',''),':',''),'.',''),'+',''),'T','')" data-type="number" order="descending" />
    <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 4">
        <li>
        <xsl:value-of select="id" /> - 
        <xsl:value-of select="timestamp" />
        </li>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

First you use translate() to remove non numerical characters from the timestamp, which effectively turns it into a number which can easily be sorted.

Then you sort the list and output only the first 3 items.

The output is the following:

```
4 - 2013-10-23T14:52:08.000+02:00
3 - 2013-10-02T12:47:47.000+02:00
6 - 2013-10-02T12:44:24.000+02:00
```

This is tested using the XSLT transformation which is built into .Net.  It uses XPath 1.0.